# use JDA delete message 10 seconds after sending

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am making a discord bot that sends an embed to display a users inventory(im making a game bot). To avoid clutter I want to delete the message after 10-20 seconds. Anyone know how I can do this(If you completely understand the questions then pls dont say, "oh you need to follow blah blah format"). I am using Java eclipse with JDA.

Yes, I've looked it up and I couldn't find anything for JDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `queueAfter` which will delay the execution of the `RestAction` provided by `delete()`.

```java
public static void deleteAfter(Message message, int delay) {
    message.delete().queueAfter(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

This method can be used inside the success callback for your `sendMessage` action.

```java
someMethod().queue((result) -> { // the type for "result" is the T in RestAction<T>
    System.out.println(result);
}, (failure) -> { // failure is always a Throwable
    failure.printStackTrace();
});
```

I recommend reading the documentation and wiki:

- [RestAction javadocs](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html)
- [JDA wiki](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/7%29-Using-RestAction)

Comment: thanks man. This would help if I were still making the bot lol