# How do I let delete my java discord bots automaticly after 5 seconds?

Tags: java, discord-jda

How do I let my discord java bot to delete the message after for example 5 seconds???

```
String[] messageArgs = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().toLowerCase().split(" ");
for (String args : messageArgs) {
    if (blacklistWords.contains(args)) {
        if (memberRoles.contains(warn0)) {                          
            event.getMessage().delete().queue();            
            event.getMessage().getChannel().sendMessage
            ("**" + MemberMention + "** unterlasse bitte diese **Wortwahl.**"
             + "\nBei **3 Verwarnungen** wirst du **gekickt!**").queue();

            event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(user, warn1).complete();
            event.getJDA().getGuildById(Secrets.guildID).removeRoleFromMember(user, warn0).complete();

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use JDA delete message 10 seconds after sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564998/use-jda-delete-message-10-seconds-after-sending)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be to pass a consumer to your .queue method when sending the message. Together with using RestAction#queueAfter you would get

```
channel.sendMessage("message").queue(message -> message.delete().queueAfter(5, 
TIMEUNIT.SECONDS);
```

see [queue with Consumer](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#queue(java.util.function.Consumer)) and [queueAfter](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#queueAfter(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

There is another way of doing this using [RestAction#delay](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#delay(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

Answer (score -1):

You can start a new thread and pause that thread before running the delete command on the message. That way you won't cause issues with the other code lines.

```java
String[] messageArgs = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().toLowerCase().split(" ");
for (String args : messageArgs) {
    if (blacklistWords.contains(args)) {
        if (memberRoles.contains(warn0)) {

            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // pause for 5 seconds
                        wait(5000);

                        event.getMessage().delete().queue();

                        event.getMessage().getChannel().sendMessage
                            ("**" + MemberMention + "** unterlasse bitte diese **Wortwahl.**"
                                > here + "\nBei **3 Verwarnungen** wirst du **gekickt!**").queue();

                        event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(user, warn1).complete();
                        event.getJDA().getGuildById(Secrets.guildID).removeRoleFromMember(user, warn0)
                            .complete();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.start();

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `wait` is not a proper way to sleep. And you don't need to create a new thread for this either. The proper way is to use a ScheduledExecutorService or `queueAfter`. This is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564998/use-jda-delete-message-10-seconds-after-sending

Comment: thank you for you answer, i knew `queueAfter`, but I dont know, how to delete the message with `queueAfter`. I also read the post below.

Answer (score -2):

Just put a pause in with something like `Thread.sleep(5000);` before you call the function to delete the message. This will pause for 5000 milliseconds or 5 seconds.

Comment: This would make the bot unresponsive for 5 seconds. Not a good solution.