# Delete MessageEmbed after 10 seconds using JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I want to send a MessageEmbed with a bot, which should be deleted after 10 seconds. For simple text messages I found this solution: [use JDA delete message 10 seconds after sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564998/use-jda-delete-message-10-seconds-after-sending), but no solution for embedded messages.

Comment: It is the same way for embeds. Embeds are only a part of messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  channel.sendMessage(msg).queue(m -> m.delete().queueAfter(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

---

In JDA when you queue an action you can add a consumer that executes after the action is successfully completed, in the consumer you can do anything you want like deleting the message 10 seconds afterward.

Read more about that here: https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html